# Music player which features taskbar toolbar controls, or a taskbar "mini player"?

Tags: windows, open-source, windows-7, music, mp3

I'm looking for a music player (preferably open source) which features a taskbar toolbar player, like older versions of iTunes and Windows Media Player had.

Examples:

[image]

[image]